# Calculating average from user (through prompt input data) in a while loop until some condition in Python

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I have written the following code which is working fine for me and I want to write the same code in a function (i.e., def function_name()) - which I have tried below as well but that's not a good approach and it's poorly written). So, how can I fix the code and how can I put input in an argument of my function name upon invoking/calling argument so that I can get my ultimate answer.

```
# Normal code:
from statistics import mean 
lst = list()
while True:
    user_int = input("Enter a number: ")
    if user_int == "done":
        break
    try:
        float_user_int = float(user_int)
    except:
        print("Bad input. Enter a valid number")
        continue 
    lst.append(float_user_int)
print(mean(lst))
```

```
# Function Method I have tried which is working fine but it's poorly written and not yielding correct output. Rather, I am getting an error i.e., NameError: name 'float_user_input' is not defined. How can I write user_input integer numbers in an argument of my function name?

def avg_list(float_user_input):
    from statistics import mean # import statistics
    lst = list()
    while True:
        user_int = input("Enter a number: ")
        if user_int == "done":
            break
        try:
            float_user_int = float(user_int)
        except:
            print("Bad input. Enter a valid number")
            continue # quit()
        lst.append(float_user_int)
    return(mean(lst)) # statistics.mean()
print(avg_list(float_user_input))
```

```
# This is the one I tried and it seems to be working with function but I don't think this code is perfect because I have done nothing in it except copy pasting the entire code under def function statement. How can I put user input number in an argument of function name?

def avg_list():
    from statistics import mean # import statistics
    lst = list()
    while True:
        user_int = input("Enter a number: ")
        if user_int == "done":
            break
        try:
            float_user_int = float(user_int)
        except:
            print("Bad input. Enter a valid number")
            continue # quit()
        lst.append(float_user_int)
    return(mean(lst)) # statistics.mean()
print(avg_list())
```

Your help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? It looks ok upon first inspection.

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: @quamrana I am getting an error if I run the second code. You can try running that and let me know what do you get. How can I put user_input number in an argument of a function?

Comment: @komatiraju032 Did you run the second code?  You can try running that and let me know what do you get. How can I put user_input number in an argument of a function?

Comment: `print(avg_list(float_user_input))` you didnt define float_user_input thats why u get an error. However you do not need this argument.

Comment: No, sorry, *you* can let *me* know what *you* get. Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @FionaDaniel why do you want to put user input in function argument?

Comment: @IronHandOdin Can you please share your code below in a function form.

Comment: @quamrana Can you please share your code below in a function form.I am getting this traceback i.e., NameError: name 'float_user_input' is not defined.

Comment: @komatiraju032 Do you think I have done correctly? I have also included the third code. Did you see that? And can u please share ur code below as an how would you write?

Comment: @FionaDaniel there is nothing wrong with your code

Comment: Well, your third snippet of code seems just fine. I don't understand what you want to accomplish with "How can I put user input number in an argument of function name?
"

Comment: @quamrana I don't want to get a tracebook which I have got in my 2nd attempt code. So, what should I do? Did you see my second attempt code and the tracebook I got there?

Comment: Yes, I saw the partial traceback you posted and nobody *wants* to get a traceback, except when there really is something wrong with the program. Others have commented on how to fix that. You could upvote the answer from jaleksi. Also, what about the answer from "Iron Hand Odin"? Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float_user_input` from function declaration and function call

Comment: You are saying about the third code attempt in my post above? Is that you are talking about?

Comment: Dont you think thats a poorly written and I would be just copy pasting the entire code in define function thing.

Comment: This answer was written in response to your second snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a function which takes input list from user such as `get_input_list` and calculate the mean as below:

```
from statistics import mean # import statistics

def avg_list(input_list):
    return(mean(input_list))


def get_input_list():
    # Take user input here
    lst = list()
    while True:
        user_int = input("Enter a number: ")
        if user_int == "done":
            break
        try:
            float_user_int = float(user_int)
        except:
            print("Bad input. Enter a valid number")
            continue
        lst.append(float_user_int)
    return lst

# call function
print(avg_list(get_input_list()))
```

Comment: This is working but how can you write everything and cover in one function instead of creating two separate functions? Can you share that please?

Comment: It is important to keep concepts and functions seperated. In your third code snippet you already have the whole process in one function.

Comment: How's my third code attempt? Is that fine? Or it's poorly written? 
Though I am getting correct output!

Comment: Your third snippet is just fine. The only *minor* things I would change are: `lst = []` and `return mean(lst)`

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with your code above but as i said in the first comment you may divide your function into two parts. If you interested in developing your code you can visit  here https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @IronHandOdin I am net to programming and these things like Stack Overflow and all. What is this codereview thing and how is it different from stack overflow?